# Swiper перелистывание только одного слайда за раз

Tags: вёрстка, слайдер, swiper

Мне нужно, чтобы можно было перелистывать только один слайд за раз, как бы далеко ты не отводил палец. Показывается за раз 3 слайда, поэтому, если резко и далеко провести мышкой или пальцем, то можно перескочить пару слайдов. Можно ли это как-то сделать, чтобы всегда перелистывался только один слайд?

Comment: вы же вчера задавали этот же вопрос.

Comment: Да, но до сих пор никто не ответил. Поэтому я попробовал добавить ещё раз на случай, вдруг увидит тот, кто не видел вчера и сможет дать ответ